# Button onclick inside fragment is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-button

I am trying to set / override the `onclick` method for a button (R.id.buy_button) inside one of my views (inside a fragment). The application doesn't return errors. However it does not trigger the onclick method. I'm not sure if my implementation is wrong or perhaps my button is incorrectly configured. Any help / comments / guidance would be appreciated.

**My onCreateView is here:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
    Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buy_button);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
}
```

**My entire fragment code:**

```
public static class AlbumsFragment extends ListFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public AlbumsFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle b){
            super.onActivityCreated(b);

            ListView listView = getListView();
            List<Album> albums = null;

            albums = Album.listAll(Album.class);
            Log.i("ALBUMS", albums.toString());
            ArrayAdapter<Album> adapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<Album>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView,  albums);
            if (!albums.equals("")) {
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
            Button b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buy_button);
            b.setOnClickListener(this);

            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
        }

        public void gotoPurchaseWeb() {
            Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, PurchaseSong.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        public static AlbumsFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            AlbumsFragment fragment = new AlbumsFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.buy_button:
                    Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PurchaseSong.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**My list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:showDividers="middle|end"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/black"/>

        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/zero_space"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/zero_space"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="24.33" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
        android:text="@string/buy_album"
        android:id="@+id/buy_button"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
        android:paddingTop="7dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```

**My entire project:**
https://github.com/markbratanov/MyFitPlayer/tree/master/Player/src/main/java/com/markbratanov/myfitplayer

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should return your View instead of returning new inflated instance of your View in onCreateView callback function inside of your Fragment.

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
```

instead use :

```
return view;
```

Comment: Yep create view reurns view without assigned onClick listener to the button

Comment: @user3455363 : absolutely

Comment: @Arash This makes sense. Tried it and returns a NullPointerException. 

The button is located in a different layout file (list_item) than the  view for the fragment (fragment_item_list). How do I load both?

Comment: @markbratanov : if your button is inside of your main layout so you should set listener for that button with your main Activity context.you can access to your MainActivity context by using  getActivity() inside of your Fragment . so you can use Button b = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.buy_button);

Comment: I spent an HOUR figuring this partuclar problem out. thank you.

Comment: not work !!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

do this in onCreateView view method u need to inflate fragment like this for button click

```
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank3,
            container, false);
   Button bt1=(Button)view.findViewbyId(R.id.buttton);
   bt1.setOnclick...
   //then return in on create view.
    return view;
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. My button `onclick` listener was not working inside the fragment.

Try this: add the **android:onclick=""** inside the button XML before the closing TAG and create a class inside the `mainActivity.java` file having the same name as the class name you declared inside the XML. Then do whatever you want to do in the `onclick` event. Write it inside the class you created recently for the click event.